# Getting 404 not found using SignalR.Hosting.Self

Tags: signalr

I've got the following server code:

```
var server = new Server("http://localhost:13170/");
server.MapConnection<EchoConnection>("echo");
server.Start();
```

But when I connect to it from my client code:

```
var connection = new Connection("http://localhost:13170/echo");
connection
    .Start()
    .ContinueWith(t =>
                  {
                      if (!t.IsFaulted)
                          connection.Send("Hello");
                      else
                          Console.WriteLine(t.Exception);
                  });
```

...it reports:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the parameter to `MapConnection` must start with a slash:

```
server.MapConnection<EchoConnection>("/echo");
```

This is because `Server.ResolvePath` prepends a slash before looking up the URL in the mappings.